# Making one radio button select a second mirrored radio button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I imagine this should be pretty simple... anyways I have two mirrored sets of radio buttons, say set A and set B

In set a, there is button 1, 2, and 3

In set b, there is also button 1, 2, and 3

The behavior I want is when I click button 1 in set a, it automatically checks button 1 in set b.

Same for 2A and 2B, and 3A and 3B.

Can anyone explain how to do this? It seems like an extremely simple function, but apparently it's impossible to find an answer through Google and it seems like nobody's ever asked this here before either... :/

I'd like to do with HTML / Javascript. **NO JQUERY.**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Checking `if(o[i].checked!=true)` before setting `o[i].checked=true` to avoid infinite feedback.

```js
function radioChanged(name, value) {
  var n=name=="a"?"b":"a";
  var o=document.getElementsByName(n);
  for(var i=0; i<o.length; i++)
    if(o[i].value==value)
      if(o[i].checked!=true)
        o[i].checked=true;
};
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="a" value="1" id="A1"
  onchange="radioChanged(this.name, this.value)">
<label for="A1">A1</label></input>
<input type="radio" name="a" value="2" id="A2"
  onchange="radioChanged(this.name, this.value)">
<label for="A2">A2</label></input>
<input type="radio" name="a" value="3" id="A3"
  onchange="radioChanged(this.name, this.value)">
<label for="A3">A3</label></input>
<hr>
<input type="radio" name="b" value="1" id="B1"
  onchange="radioChanged(this.name, this.value)">
<label for="B1">B1</label></input>
<input type="radio" name="b" value="2" id="B2"
  onchange="radioChanged(this.name, this.value)">
<label for="B2">B2</label></input>
<input type="radio" name="b" value="3" id="B3"
  onchange="radioChanged(this.name, this.value)">
<label for="B3">B3</label></input>
```